# Cannot get min_element to work in C++

Tags: c++, linux, redhat, min, minimum

I'm writing a small recursive algorithm. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<int> coins;

int checkchange(int left) {
    vector<int> choices (coins.size());
    if (left == 0)
        return 0;
    else {
        int min;
        for (int i=0;i<coins.size();i++) {
            choices.at(i) = (1 + checkchange(left - coins.at(i)));
        }
        return min_element(choices.front(),choices.back());
    }
}


int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        int c,m,temp,change;
        cin >> c >> m;
        for (int j=0;j<c;j++) {
            cin >> temp;
            coins.push_back(temp);
        }

        for (int j=0;j<m;j++) {
            cin >> temp;
            change = checkchange(temp);
            cout << change;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> In file included from 
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/algorithm:62, 
>                    from burningcoins.cpp:3: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h: 
>   In function ‘_FIter std::min_element(_FIter, _FIter) [with _FIter = 
>   int]’: burningcoins.cpp:19:   instantiated from here 
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5998: 
>   error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ 
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5998: 
>   error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’

I've tried compiling with both g++ and gcc, both give me the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

New Code:

```
int checkchange(int left) {
    vector<int> choices (coins.size());
    if (left == 0)
        return 0;
    else {
        for (int i=0;i<coins.size();i++) {
            choices[i] = (1 + checkchange(left - coins.at(i)));
        }
        return *min_element(choices.begin(), choices.end());
    }
}
```

New error message:

> /tmp/ccV3VLsK.o: In function `main': <br/>
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x16a): undefined reference to`std::cin' 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&)' <br/>
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to`std::cin' 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&)' <br/>
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x19b): undefined reference to`std::basic_istream >::operator>>(int&)' 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `std::cin' <br/>
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to`std::basic_istream >::operator>>(int&)' 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x1ec): undefined reference to `std::cin' <br/>
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to`std::basic_istream >::operator>>(int&)' 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `std::cout' <br/>
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x20d): undefined reference to`std::basic_ostream >::operator<<(int)' 
>   /tmp/ccV3VLsK.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)': <br/>
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x261): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::Init()' 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text+0x266): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' <br/>
>   /tmp/ccV3VLsK.o: In function`std::vector >::_M_range_check(unsigned long) const': 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE14_M_range_checkEm[std::vector >::_M_range_check(unsigned long) const]+0x2d): undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)' <br/>
>   /tmp/ccV3VLsK.o: In function`std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, int const&)': 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi[std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, int const&)]+0x259): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch' <br/>
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi[std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&)]+0x2be): undefined reference to`__cxa_rethrow' 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi[std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, int const&)]+0x2c8): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch' <br/>
>   /tmp/ccV3VLsK.o: In function`std::vector >::_M_check_len(unsigned long, char const*) const': 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE12_M_check_lenEmPKc[std::vector >::_M_check_len(unsigned long, char const*) const]+0x4c): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)' <br/>
>   /tmp/ccV3VLsK.o: In function`__gnu_cxx::new_allocator::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)': 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)' <br/>
>   /tmp/ccV3VLsK.o: In function`__gnu_cxx::new_allocator::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)': 
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)]+0x35): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()' <br/>
>   burningcoins.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)]+0x45): undefined reference to`operator new(unsigned long)' 
>   /tmp/ccV3VLsK.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0' <br/>
>   /tmp/ccV3VLsK.o:(.eh_frame+0x4f): undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0' 
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: min_element(choices.begin(),choices.end());

Comment: Careful with the `using namespace std;`. You have a variable named `min` and a function named `min`. It's not quite a conflict, but it's getting close.

Comment: `min_element` works properly. You're just not using it properly. You might want to change your question title.

Comment: Yeah I changed it, using it like you proposed and its still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::min_element` takes a range. `front` and `back` return references to actual values. You should be using the `begin` and `end` methods to return an iterator to the corresponding positions in the vector:

```
min_element(choices.begin(), choices.end());
//                  ^^^^^            ^^^
```

If you find this tedious, you can create a function which wraps around the standard `min_element`:

```
template <class Container>
auto min_element(Container c) -> decltype(std::min_element(c.begin(), c.end()))
{
    return std::min_element(c.begin(), c.end());
}
```

And use it as:

```
min_element(choices);
```

Comment: I've changed it to what you said, and get following error:
burningcoins.cpp: In function ‘int checkchange(int)’:
burningcoins.cpp:19: error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >’ to ‘int’ in return

I imagine that is because it returns a pointer. But dereferencing it with the star operator gives me even more errors?

Comment: @BananaCode Is that the only change you made?

Comment: Yes, it is the only change.

Comment: @BananaCode What are some of the errors you get when you dereference. Dereferencing is the right thing to do in this case.

Comment: burningcoins.cpp: In function ‘int checkchange(int)’:
burningcoins.cpp:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token.

This is the relevant part of the code: return min_element(choices.begin(), choices.end())*;

Comment: The other issue, which you didn't point out, is that `min_element` returns the iterator, not the element itself.   You have to deference it.

Comment: @BananaCode Simple problem: You put the star in the wrong place. It should be: `*min_element(choices.begin(), choices.end())`

Comment: Yeah I realized this and changed it. Check the original post for the new error message.

Comment: @BananaCode Your other errors don't have anything to do with the original problem. You should ask another question for that.

Comment: I compiled with gcc instead of g++...sorry for the stupidity.